# find the hostname for azure web app for node server test

Tags: node.js, azure

I am trying to start node server for my first time.
I am following this tutorial: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

I am using azure web app for free testing. The problem is that they give you a loopback address of `127.0.0.1` in the example demo but since this is in azure I don't know what to put. I tried putting the public Ip address of 20.40.202.24 but it looks like all azure web apps go to that public ip then it gets routed somewhere else.

How can I test node server in azure. This is just for testing how to start the node server in azure. Thanks

I tried using 0.0.0.0 but that didn't work either. Any ideas would be awesome.

code:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

[image]

I tried using the url that comes with the webapp and append the port of 3000 to it but it failed:
[image]
I think this would work locally but I need to test how it works in azure specifically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue by spinning up a flask server instead. It handles pushing the development server to the hostname normally. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask